# With JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER activated, only mouse pressed gets executed--not dragged and released

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, mouselistener, jlayeredpane

I'm new to `JLayeredPane`, so I assume that's partly to blame for why I can't understand
WHY the mouse pressed/dragged/released methods do not execute as they should when I drag
a `txtUser` item (which has listeners attached; see bottom).

With the given code segments. Only `userMousePressed` executes when I drag.

HOWEVER, *IF* the line `layeredPane.add(userDragLetter, LayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER)` is commented out, all 3 mouse events are recognized and executed properly.

```
  private void userMousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    curUserCell.index = interpIndex(e.getXOnScreen(),ulcUser.x,txtUser[0].getWidth());

    curUserCell.background = txtUser[curUserCell.index].getBackground();

    curUserCell.content = txtUser[curUserCell.index].getText().charAt(0);

    txtUser[curUserCell.index].setBackground(B_DRAGGING);   

    txtUser[curUserCell.index].setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    int w = Integer.parseInt(e.getComponent().getName());

    userDragLetter = null; 

    Component c = txtUser[w];                            

    parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();                                         
    xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();                                            
    yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY()- gamePanel.getHeight();

    userDragLetter = (JLabel)c;                                                           
    userDragLetter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE));
    userDragLetter.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);           

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                                                                          
// If I comment out the line below, `userMouseDragged` & `userMouseReleased` DO execute

    layeredPane.add(userDragLetter, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

  }
```

This method doesn't get executed with code above 'as is':

```
private void userMouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {  

    System.out.print("User mouse dragged entered..."); // Doesn't print

    ...
}
```

This method doesn't get executed either:

```
private void userMouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("User mouse released entered..."); // Doesn't print
    ...
}
```

Here's how I assign the mouse listeners:

```
  txtUser[k].addMouseMotionListener
  (
       new MouseMotionAdapter() 
      {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) 
        {
          userMouseDragged(evt);
        }
      }
   );

  txtUser[k].addMouseListener
  (
    new MouseAdapter() 
    {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
      {   
        userMousePressed(e);
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
      {                                         //after dragging user letter
              userMouseReleased(e);
      }
    }
  );
```

(What I'm trying to do is to physically drag--i.e., have mouse pointer literally point at--a letter from `txtUser[...]` as it's dragged to a game grid. I'm not close, but as is it's broken! If I comment out the `layeredPane` line, program works as always.)

(a) Why do mouse dragged and mouse released events get ignored?

(b) What should I do to make dragged and released events trigger their methods?

Comment: Try using setLayer instead of add

Comment: I've not tested this or dug around the code, but, using add may be removing the component first, which is resetting the state, meaning that Java no longer thinks that the component is been pressed...maybe...

Comment: FIRST, @MadProgrammer, using `setLayer` is a fix in that dragged and released DO get executed, so THANKS. Second, what I'm dragging is a letter in the `JLabel` named `txtUser[w]` (I need to rename that; it used to be `JTextField`.). Since `txtUser[w]` has the listeners attached, wnen I press it, that object gets added to the `DRAG_LAYER` and disappears, so how could subsequent events find it? Is that the problem?

Comment: Think about it like this.  You already have a component on the container, you want to move it to a different layer, then use `set`.  If you don't already have the component on the container, use `add`...

Comment: One of the jobs of "add" is to first remove the component from it's previous parent. I've not checked the code to see if this checks to see if you're adding to the same parent or not though

Comment: @MadProgrammer--Thanks for the help. I always seem to be reaching beyond what I know, which isn't bad in and of itself, except--like mis-using a ladder--I skip so many steps that I fall off. In other words, I've been trying to use stuff that I haven't studied nearly enough. Worse yet, I've tried to adapt working "simple chessboard" code to work for my rather different situation, which is fine--if you understand the implications of each line of code. And I don't. BTW, I had to change back to using `add` instead of `setLayer`. All `setLayer` did was mask a problem with code logic. But THANKS!